# CSS background animation working, but have a question

Tags: css, animation

So I found this www.w3schools.com "try it yourself", 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_animatable

...and was able to partially tweak it to my needs...

```css
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s alternate infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 5s alternate infinite;
```

...however I would like to know if there is a way to make the animation "stay" in the plain colors, for longer?

As it is it just keeps changing from one to another, without any pause...

I would like for example to have red for 6 seconds, then fade, then blue for 6 second, fade again, red for 6 second, and so on infinitely... is this achievable?

EDIT:
I was sucessfully able to animate via @keyframe. Here is my "end result":
https://coresaocubo.pt/teste/cc2019/novo-teste(1).html

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/anatchim/1m7y0h9j/3/

In Chrome the first transition is preceded by a very fast "blink", after that everything works smoothly as expected... Any idea on why that blink is happening=

However in Firefox I am not getting a smooth transition between images... Can anyone point me into the right direction to achieve that? I've tried the

animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

...and variations of that, to no avail :(

Thank you so much!

Anatchim

Comment: Yes, it's possible animating opacity in `@keyframe`, for example.

Comment: @marcelo2605 sorry, I'm probably too noob, but I just can't seem to figure it out... How would you implement that here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_animatable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of the puzzle I suspect you are missing is that `@keyframe` declarations can take ***percentages*** as well as the keywords `from` and `to`.

In fact... `from` is just an alias for `0%` and `to` is just an alias for `100%`.

Knowing that you can use percentages means you can do something like the following:

```
0% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);} // Start the animation with a red background
25% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);} // 25% through the animation, the background is *still* red 
50% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);} // *Then* between 25% & 50%, the background moves to blue
```

Once you get the hang of explicitly stating which values remain the same at different `@keyframes` you can produce the type of animation which states:

- Start the animation with a red background
- Between 0% and 25%, the background *remains red*
- *Then* between 25% & 50%, the background moves to blue
- Between 50% and 75%, the background *remains blue*
- *Then* between 75% & 100%, the background moves to red

If it's a 20 second animation that means:

- 5 seconds of red
- 5 second transition from red to blue
- 5 seconds of blue
- 5 second transition from blue to red

**Working Example:**

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  animation: mymove 20s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
   25% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
   50% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
   75% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
  100% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
}

/*SHORTHAND VERSION OF THE @Keyframes ABOVE: */

/*
@keyframes mymove {
   25% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
   50%, 75% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

---

## Makng`@keyframes` syntax more concise

You'll see in the **Working Example** above, I've also shown you a *Shorthand Version* of the declared `@keyframes` animation which ends up being 2 lines instead of 5.

To reduce this part of the CSS by 60%, I did the following:

Starting with:

```
 @keyframes mymove {
    0% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
   25% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
   50% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
   75% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
  100% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
}
```

In the declaration for `#myDiv` the starting `background-color` is already explicitly stated (further up) as `rgb(255, 0, 0)` so the `@keyframes` won't need this redeclared:

```
 @keyframes mymove {
   25% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
   50% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
   75% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
}
```

Where values are the same, `@keyframes` can be comma separated on a single line:

```
 @keyframes mymove {
   25% {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
   50%, 75% {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}
}
```